# Ionic Sheet modal clicks into background

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic6

I am trying to click into and use a google map view together with a sheet modal.
However, when the modal is open clicks do not make it to the map.

Is it because of the background dismiss? How can I have both items open at the same time so that taps into the map will change the sheet modal content?

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="map-wrapper">
    <div id="map" #map></div>
  </div>

  <ion-modal id="mapModal #mapModal"
    [isOpen]="mapModalIsOpen"
    [initialBreakpoint]="0.1"
    [breakpoints]="[0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]"
    handleBehavior="cycle"
    [backdropDismiss]="false"
  >
    <ng-template>
      <ion-content class="ion-padding">
        <ion-button click="breakpoint()" expand="block">ASDF</ion-button>
      </ion-content>
    </ng-template>
  </ion-modal>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to use `backdropBreakpoint` as per the documentation.